# Baking eevee result to texture?

Tags: texture-baking

i have created a node setup useing the "shader to rgb" node as base.
Now im happy with my result and simply want to bake what i see onto a image.
(i know how baking works, i have done it a few times by now)

the main problem is, i can only bake in cycles but the "shader to rgb" node does not work in cycles, so i get wrong results.

i can not use the toon shader in my setup bcs i would need the toon shader to act as mask.

maybe there is a different way to get a mask (black and white image) for cell shading?

best thing would be if someone knows a work around for the "shader to rgb" node wich does exactly the same.